# Drupal 8 custom theme

Tags: drupal, drupal-theming, drupal-8

I have created admin theme, base on Seven theme.
The strange problem  I have, in created admin theme pages is shown content from site, like a menu. I have tried many things to fix it, no result. Maybe someone can give me advice what to do.

Comment: what mean from web page? without overlay?

Comment: Thank you for your reply,, it means content like main menu from my site (

Comment: can you upload a screenshot? maybe i can undestand well ^^

Comment: It is private, I can not. For example site/admin/content in this page the first site menu is shown then contnet page

Comment: what did u put in your .theme.yml ?